# Can't connect to mongod instance from Java on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb, maven

I just set up a Maven project with the Mongo Java driver and everything, but when I run

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost");
    MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase("test");
}
```

trying to connect to a mongod instance from the command line, it gives me

```
INFO: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
```

in the console and doesn't connect. I pretty much followed everything from [this tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/java/#).

Comment: Could you please post additional log messages? How do you determine that it does not connect?

Comment: The only console message was this: ' Sep 16, 2016 9:33:10 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}

Comment: And I can tell it's not connecting because there are no log messages from the cmd I ran mongod from

Comment: Linux or windows ?

Comment: Is the mongo server configured to listen on a TCP port?

Comment: You question does not have anything that would say that anything is wrong: a cluster was successfully created and you probably obtained a working `db` instance. You never try to use it in the above code, so where is the problem? Try adding some `query` or `insert`, anything that would actually exchange information or commands with the DB. If you say it does not connect, either explain how you know that or show an exception.

Comment: Expanding a bit on Oleg's comment: Mongo initializes eveything lazily, so creating a client object and obtaining a database/collection object from that, does not actually initiate any communication to the server. To see an actualy effect, you need to query something. Try client.listDatabaseNames() and see what happens.

Comment: Can you show me how to iterate through client.listDatabaseNames()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Oleg Skylar was right, there was actually nothing wrong with my program in the first place, it's just that I was using outdated methods to test whether it was working. Once I followed https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/java/query/ to query for test data, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

This kinda error generally happens due to incorrect version of `mongo java driver` jar or may be ***you also did not mention port number to connect mongo server***.

## Solution

Try this:

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017 );
```

instead of this:

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost");
```

and add dependencies to your `pom.xml` because you did not mention port number to connect.

If you are using older version than this may work:

```
Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
```

, and here is [full example](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-hello-world-example/) of it, see 10th step directly, if you know syntax of CRUD operation using MongoDB (NoSQL).

if you have any doubts, comment below.

Thanks.

Comment: This is the <dependency> tag in my pom.xml file: <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

Comment: And the link you posted is outdated, none of the classes that person used are still used. I also changed the first line to add the port number and nothing really changed.

Answer (score 0):

this how i connect

```
public static Document GetDocumentFromDataBase(String dataBase,String DBcollection,String field, String value) {
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(  " HEREYOURIP ",27017 );
MongoDatabase database =  mongoClient.getDatabase(dataBase);
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(DBcollection);
Document myDoc = collection.find(eq(field, value)).first();
    mongoClient.close();
    return myDoc;}
```

the eq - it  import of
**import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.eq;**